# How to do forecasting of Time series data (2 columns) using Neural Network in R?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I have data in the following format:
[image]
I want to use Neural Network for forecasting next value of A. I have already obtained lag in series A which comes out to be 37 based on AIC criteria. This is done by using the code

```
model<-nnetar(data[,2], P=1,repeats=20,lambda=NULL)
```

I wanted to use the same lag for both series A and B to predict next values of series A. The problem I am facing is `nnetar` builds a model only on 1 column and I want to use both column for forecasting and lag part needs to be intact. Is there any way, I could do that?

Comment: It is hardly possible to load your data set way into R. Please provide an excerpt using dput().

Comment: The dataset is very huge.

Comment: do something like dput(data[100,])

Comment: structure(list(Time = "42005.458333333336", Spot = 8269.7, Futures = 8316.95, 
    Spot_ret = 7.86e-05, Futures_ret = 6.61e-05), .Names = c("Time", 
"Spot", "Futures", "Spot_ret", "Futures_ret"), row.names = 100L, class = "data.frame") . Here spot_ret is column A and Futures_ret is column B

Answer (score 0):

I think natively it is hardly possible to use NNAR natively as it has a fixed NN structure, except the number of nodes in the hidden layer.

(**WARNING**: slightly crazy idea)
However, as far as i understand nnetar it uses something like a windowing approach. Therefore, it might be possible to interleave your data having A's and B's alternating. This can be done using `melt(data[,2:3])` from reshape. Afterwards you can predict A's and B's simultaneously. You need to adapt all the other parameters accordingly.

However, i would switch to a recurrent neural network library like RSNNS

Comment: How time series data is handled by RSNNS? I have used it for structured data but not for time-series data.

Comment: You can look at the functions elm an and jordan. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network

As far as I know time series are the prime example for RNNs

Comment: Will try to solve the problem using Recurrent Neural network.